# leaflet api event listener argument access

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet, geojson

I am using leaflet api with L.geoJson. the parts of code are

```
var indiaLayer= L.geoJson(india, {style: {weight: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        color: '#F7BE81',
        dashArray: '10',
        fillOpacity: 0.2}});
```

now i define an event listener on indiaLayer as

```
indiaLayer.on('click', clicked);
```

now if i want to access the first argument i.e. india inside clicked function, what should i use?. I consulted dom tree and figured out it to be

```
alert(this._layers.22.feature.id);
```

but it throws syntax error. can anyone help me out of it? thank you

i am attaching full code also

```
<html>
<head>


<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.css" />
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="india.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>


<body>
<div id = "map1" style="width: 1100px; height: 400px"> </div>
<div id = "zoom" style="width: 100px;  height: 100px"></div>
<div id = "select" style="width: 100px; height:100px"></div>

<script>



var area = L.map('map1', {center: [27.8800,78.0800], zoom: 4 });

L.tileLayer('http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/raj333.map-gugr5h08/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(area);











function zoomDeal()

{

var zoom=document.getElementById("zoom");
zoom.innerHTML= area.getZoom();



}




area.on('zoomend',zoomDeal);



var indiaLayer= L.geoJson(india, {style: {weight: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        color: '#F7BE81',
        dashArray: '10',
        fillOpacity: 0.2}});

        area.addLayer(indiaLayer);

        function clicked(){

    if (area.getZoom() == 4) {

        if (this.options.style.fillOpacity == 0.5)
    {

        this.setStyle({fillOpacity: 0.2});
    this.options.style.fillOpacity=0.2;
    var select = document.getElementById("select");
    select.innerHTML = "";
    }

    else
    {   
    this.setStyle({fillOpacity: 0.5});   
    this.options.style.fillOpacity=0.5;  
    var select = document.getElementById("select");
    //select.innerHTML = "india";       
    alert(this._layers.22.feature.id);
    }
    }
        }

        indiaLayer.on('click', clicked);                
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `22` is not a valid identifier name, hence you have to use bracket notation, not dot notation, to access it. Have you ever seen an array accessed with `arr.0`?

Comment: @FelixKling thanks.....but when i use array notation it tells
TypeError: this._layers[0] is undefined
i used alert(this._layers[0].feature.id);

Comment: Well, this only means that `this._layers` doesn't haven't a property `0`, i.e. an element at position `0`. You said it has the property `22`, so why not try that?

Comment: @FelixKling thanks....but i used it before and it didn't work..can you please tell me what should i do ..i am attaching the link for my dom tree , may be it can give you more picture https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-XA2uVZaFFTT3FBeEYtcDkzc1E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You tried `this._layers[22].feature.id` and it did not work?

Comment: @FelixKling yes now it works...earlier i used this._layers.22.feature.id thanks a lot
but i want to clear my concept....so can you tell me when should i use layers[22] and layers.22.....like in other dom elements i simply use dot for accessing elements. here 22 is in blue may be thats the indication...if you want to add something, i would be gratefull

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36534/discussion-between-user609306-and-felix-kling)

Answer (score 1):

Using the specific leaflet given id in the click handler can result in problems, as Leaflet might assign a different id if you load somewhere else.

The click handler on default throws in the `event` argument. Meaning that if you'd change your clicked function definition to:

```
function clicked (e) {
  // do stuff etc.
}
```

You would be able to access the origin of the click (with `e.target`). In this case the layer.

Even nicer would be adding an `onEachFeature` function to the layer definition (where it reads out the JSON). Like in the example here: http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html

The `onEachFeature` (http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-oneachfeature) gives you direct access to the feature that you try to access so to do what you want e.g.:

```
L.geoJson(india, {
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    layer.on('click', function (e) {
      alert(e.target.feature.id)
    })
  }
});
```